# Visual Studio SDK - How to add a margin glyph on command invoked?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

How can I modify this sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361745.aspx to have glyphs added to the margin when a button I added is clicked?

I have a button which creates a special kind of breakpoint. I would like this kind to be recognized by my own margin glyph. So I wrote the GetTags method in my Tagger class as follows:

```
    IEnumerable<ITagSpan<MyBreakpointTag>> ITagger<MyBreakpointTag>.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
    {
        if (BreakpointManager != null)
        {
            DTE2 ide = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
            Document document = ide.ActiveDocument;

            foreach (SnapshotSpan span in spans)
            {
                ITextSnapshot textSnapshot = span.Snapshot;
                foreach (ITextSnapshotLine textSnapshotLine in textSnapshot.Lines)
                {
                    if (BreakpointManager.IsMyBreakpointAt(document.FullName, textSnapshotLine.LineNumber + 1))
                    {
                        yield return new TagSpan<MyBreakpointTag>(new SnapshotSpan(textSnapshotLine.Start, 1),
                                new MyBreakpointTag());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, glyphs are added after moving the cursor to a different line of code or making changes to the code. What do I have to do to have glyphs added right after the button is clicked?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I edited my question in response to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetTags is called by the editor whenever a layout happens, but the editor won't call it for any random reason. (Think: how would it know when to call you?) You need to raise the TagsChanged event from your tagger to say the tags for a given span changed, and then it'll call GetTags again to refresh.

As an unrelated piece of advice: you shouldn't be using DTE.ActiveDocument in your GetTags for a few reasons:

1. GetTags should be as fast as possible...calling DTE methods are rarely fast.
2. Imagine you have two files open, and GetTags is called for the non-active file. That would have *both* files looking at the same filename which is probably bad. There's code [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f6ef03a-df6b-4670-856e-f4a539fbfbe1/how-get-document-name-of-an-iwpftextview?forum=vseditor) that shows how to fetch the file name from an ITextBuffer.

Comment: What works perfectly?  This is marked as the answer, but the goal was to determine how to raise the TagsChanged event from a tool window button click (for example).   I am reading this and I still have no idea how to accomplish that.  If the user clicks a button, HOW do you trigger and raise the TagsChanged event so the glyphs are refreshed?

Comment: Is there a way to raise a TagsChanged event from menu command. I want to update the textview tags after a process finished. Thank you.

Comment: @madufit1 In a nutshell, you have some way to find your tagger and then have it raise tags changed. You should ask a new question on StackOverflow with further details, as comments here aren't big enough to properly answer it.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski thank you very much for your reply. There are few question raised and still unanswered in the stackoverflow regarding this issue. For example  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760891/visual-studio-mef-extension-force-margin-glyphs-to-be-updated-or-redraw?rq=1

Comment: I'll add a new question after doing more research on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is copied from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760891/visual-studio-mef-extension-force-margin-glyphs-to-be-updated-or-redraw?noredirect=1&lq=1). Basically, changing from using ITaggerProvider to IViewTaggerProvider allowed me to redraw the glyphs. I used the *Implementing a Brace Matching Tagger Provider* section in [Walkthrough: Displaying Matching Braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760891/visual-studio-mef-extension-force-margin-glyphs-to-be-updated-or-redraw?noredirect=1&lq=1) example to make these changes.

Using the IViewTaggerProvider, you can then call

```
TagsChanged?.Invoke(this, new SnapshotSpanEventArgs(
                              new SnapshotSpan(
                                      SourceBuffer.CurrentSnapshot,
                                      0, 
                                      SourceBuffer.CurrentSnapshot.Length)));
```

in your functions to explicitly call GetTags and go over the spans in the current snapshot.