# VS Extension: Toggle a Margin Glyph example

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mef, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

This is in reference to writing a Visual Studio extension or MEF.

MS Walkthrough: Creating a Margin Glyph example

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361745.aspx

How do you **toggle** a margin glyph via a tool window button?

So click button... glyph disappears, click button... glyph reappears (at location of cursor).

The issue is getting a margin glyph to **redraw**, **refresh** or **re-render** on command.

So for the purposes of this question, you can assume my project is identical to the MS Walkthrough linked at the top.

How do you get a glyph to update?

Answer (score 1):

If you're following the pattern described there, you should raise the TagsChanged event with the appropriate span from the tagger object.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760891/visual-studio-mef-extension-force-margin-glyphs-to-be-updated-or-redraw) is link to an answer that I had to a similar question. First take a look at the *Implementing a Brace Matching Tagger Provider* section in Walkthrough: Displaying Matching Braces example to change using a `ITaggerProvider` to `IViewTaggerProvider`. Then you can call

```
TagsChanged?.Invoke(this, new SnapshotSpanEventArgs(new SnapshotSpan(
    SourceBuffer.CurrentSnapshot, 0, SourceBuffer.CurrentSnapshot.Length)));
```

to explicitly call GetTags for the spans in the current snapshot.